# Adding objects into a list and showing them simultaneously on a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, oop

So, i have a empty list and a listBox inside Form1, and i want the user to add "Car" objects there. To select which Car he wants to add, i made another form, Form2.

So the Form1 list goes like this:

```
List<Car> listCars= new List<Car>();
```

And i also made a function in Form1, so the Form2 can pass to Form1 which Car object will be added:

```
public void addCar(Car c)
    {
        listCars.Add(c);
        listBox.DataSource = listCars;
        listBox.DisplayMember = "carName";
        listBox.ValueMember = "idCar";
        listBox.Refresh();
    }
```

The Form2 has a button that activate the Form1 addCar function, passing to it the selected Car object:

```
 private void btnAdd_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form1.addCar(selectedCar);
        this.Close();
    }
```

So, what happens when i try to add a Car to the Form1 listBox, it adds only the first one i selected, and if i try to keep adding new cars, the listbox keep showing only the first one i added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work !!

Use following code :

```
    public void addCar(Car c)
{
    listCars.Add(c);

    listBox.DataSource = null;     //Make Datasource null otherwise you have to use IObservable collection

    listBox.DataSource = listCars;
    listBox.DisplayMember = "carName";
    listBox.ValueMember = "idCar";
    listBox.Refresh();                // Not necessary !
}
```

**listBox.DataSource = null;**

Comment: Ok, so i removed listBox.Refresh, but listCars doesn't have DataSource property.
I'll take a further look at the IObservable, thank you for the tip!

Comment: Use listBox.DataSource = null; instead of listCars.DataSource = null; (there was typing mistake, see updated code section)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Form1 reinitializes listCars. Try to debug addCar method and see whether it's empty or not.